# ffmpeg library compile for .so files (libavutil.so, libavcore.so, libavcodec.so etc)

Tags: android, ffmpeg, shared-libraries

I want to use ffmpeg library in my Android Application. I have downloaded the source from [here](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-3.0.1.tar.bz2)

And I followed the steps INSTALL.md file to build the library. (Compilation Environment is OSX)
Unfortunately I'm getting only the .a files (like libavutil.a, libavcore.a, libavcodec.a etc).

How can I compile the library to produce the .so files.
Is there any configuration option to change?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have compiled the source in Linux machine and successfully got the .so files.

While compiling you need to specify the configuration option:

```
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static
```

This will give only the shared library files (.so files).

Comment: See also [documentaion](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) and project [example](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/libav_MJPEG-transcode-VP9_C_Universe/tree/main).